Masstransit Message Data repository error
I am facing a problem when i try to read the MessageData value at the consumer end. Here is the set up i am using. I have a producer which will read the embedded pdf file convert it to byte[] and add it to the byte[] property.
I am using aws S3 bucket for message data repository, i see that  byte[] which will be MessageData<byte[]> field is identified correctly and stored to AWS s3 bucket  but ,  at consumer end when i try to tread the same it is throwing the following
error.
'((MassTransit.MessageData.Values.DeserializedMessageData<byte[]>)request.AttachmentUpdate.Attachments[0].Attachment).Value' threw an exception of type 'MassTransit.MessageDataException'
Also when i catch the exception in try catch i see  this error:
The message data was not loaded: urn:file:y897andympc97tggh3kae8ayyy
This line of code is throwing the error -->
var file = await request?.AttachmentUpdate?.AttachmentFile.Value;
Not able to figure out what is wrong here
setup detail :

AWS S3 for Datarepository
Local stack message broker


Stack Overflow is not a valid support channel. If you want help, you'll need to provide a complete standalone repository that demonstrates the problem via a GitHub discussion or contact support directly.
